# Execution failed for task ':app:checkDevDebugDuplicateClasses'

Tags: android, flutter, dart, build.gradle, pubspec

I am using the following libraries

```
idenfy_sdk_flutter: 2.0.0
flutterpluginfidologinapi:
  hosted:
    name: flutterpluginfidologinapi
    url: https://flutter.dev.loginid.io
  version: 0.61.33
```

and getting the following errors after adding 'flutterpluginfidologinapi':

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDevDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
   > Duplicate class a.a found in modules jetified-android-sdk-0.92.36-runtime (login.api.native:android-sdk:0.92.36) and jetified-sdk-api-7.7.0-runtime (com.github.idenfy:sdk-api:7.7.0)
     Duplicate class b.a found in modules jetified-android-sdk-0.92.36-runtime (login.api.native:android-sdk:0.92.36) and jetified-sdk-api-7.7.0-runtime (com.github.idenfy:sdk-api:7.7.0)
     Duplicate class c.a found in modules jetified-android-sdk-0.92.36-runtime (login.api.native:android-sdk:0.92.36) and jetified-sdk-api-7.7.0-runtime (com.github.idenfy:sdk-api:7.7.0)
     Duplicate class d.a found in modules jetified-android-sdk-0.92.36-runtime (login.api.native:android-sdk:0.92.36) and jetified-sdk-api-7.7.0-runtime (com.github.idenfy:sdk-api:7.7.0)
     Duplicate class d.b found in modules jetified-android-sdk-0.92.36-runtime (login.api.native:android-sdk:0.92.36) and jetified-sdk-api-7.7.0-runtime (com.github.idenfy:sdk-api:7.7.0)
     Duplicate class d.b$a found in modules jetified-android-sdk-0.92.36-runtime (login.api.native:android-sdk:0.92.36) and jetified-sdk-api-7.7.0-runtime (com.github.idenfy:sdk-api:7.7.0)
     Duplicate class d.b$b found in modules jetified-android-sdk-0.92.36-runtime (login.api.native:android-sdk:0.92.36) and jetified-sdk-api-7.7.0-runtime (com.github.idenfy:sdk-api:7.7.0)
     Duplicate class e.a found in modules jetified-android-sdk-0.92.36-runtime (login.api.native:android-sdk:0.92.36) and jetified-sdk-api-7.7.0-runtime (com.github.idenfy:sdk-api:7.7.0)
     Duplicate class f.a found in modules jetified-android-sdk-0.92.36-runtime (login.api.native:android-sdk:0.92.36) and jetified-sdk-api-7.7.0-runtime (com.github.idenfy:sdk-api:7.7.0)
     Duplicate class f.b found in modules jetified-android-sdk-0.92.36-runtime (login.api.native:android-sdk:0.92.36) and jetified-sdk-api-7.7.0-runtime (com.github.idenfy:sdk-api:7.7.0)
     Duplicate class g.a found in modules jetified-android-sdk-0.92.36-runtime (login.api.native:android-sdk:0.92.36) and jetified-sdk-api-7.7.0-runtime (com.github.idenfy:sdk-api:7.7.0)
     Duplicate class h.a found in modules jetified-android-sdk-0.92.36-runtime (login.api.native:android-sdk:0.92.36) and jetified-sdk-api-7.7.0-runtime (com.github.idenfy:sdk-api:7.7.0)

     Go to the documentation to learn how to <a href="d.android.com/r/tools/classpath-sync-errors">Fix dependency resolution errors</a>.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 49s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDevDebug failed with exit code 1
```

gradle.properties file contains:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
android.enableR8=true
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

I have tried different solutions given by other similar questions in StackOverflow but in vain.

most of the solutions were suggesting to exclude modules, so i tried to do so with different modules but getting the same error every time

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude module: 'com.github.idenfy'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by updating the Flipper SDK version. The `FLIPPER_VERSION` was 0.33.1 and changed to 0.99.0.